# User Header Search Paths for Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have two paths that I want Xcode to search for headers:

> "/myproject/lib1/include"
>     "/myproject/lib2/include"

What's the correct syntax for adding those two paths inside Xcode's User Header Search Paths? I tried
    "/myproject/lib1/include";"/myproject/lib2/include"

But it didn't work. It complained that object1.h not found. object1 is inside /myproject/lib1/include

I already added the whole /myproject/lib1/include folder and /myproject/lib2/include folder into the target project.

Comment: In what way did it not work? What error did you get? When you say "Xcode's User Header Search Paths", what do you mean? In the project? In the target? Where? Please add some detail about what you tried and what the result was.

Comment: ^look under build settings there's a section called User Header Search Paths.

Comment: Yes, it's there a couple times. Did you set it for the project or the target?

Comment: I added the whole include folder and set it to target.

Answer (score 32):

Dd you actually put the leading /into the path? Because that's an absolute path and probably not what you mean.

You can pass it the relative location using `$(SRCROOT)` which expands the the directory containing the Xcode project file.

So, assuming your project file is in the `myroject` directory you should put this in your header search paths:

```
$(SRCROOT)/lib1/include
$(SRCROOT)/lib2/include
```

Comment: the entry space of header search path only has one line. Do you need to put those in quotes? and semicolon as separator?

Comment: Put one on each line.

Comment: yeah, I did. and when it expanded, it looks just like my absolute path. it's the same thing. it still complains of cannot find object1.h which inside /lib1/include folder.  Even though I add the whole include folder to the target project, but I don't see the target membership when I right clicked its properties. That makes me wonder whether object1.h is truly been added to target. I don't want to add one  .h file to target at one time, I want to add everything inside include folder to target.

Comment: Are you adding a library or a framework? If it's a library, or code you have added directly, you just need to have the headers in the Xcode project and (optionally) add a library search path if you are using libraries (.a files)

Comment: No, it's not .a or .so library. It's just .h, .hpp files that contains the class files.

Comment: oh, wait, it seems like the compiler doesn't like ; semicolon separator between the two paths. I took it out , the original error gone, now there 's something else.

Comment: It seems that Xcode replaces $SRCROOT with an absolute path immediately after typing it into the search path.  This won't work for us; our sourcecode is in svn.  The path will be different for each user.  How can I specify a search path relative to the *local* value of $SRCROOT?

Answer (score 10):

Suppose you want to use your project directory, then you should use:

```
"$PROJECT_DIR"
```

Double quotes are advised if your project path has spaces.

Enable recursive if you want to search within the folders as well. 
Alternatively, you can use `"$(SRCROOT)"`

Comment: Thanks for the "Double quotes are advised if your project path has spaces"

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple header paths, use SPACE to divide them, or double click the input text box of header pathS for advance setting.
Another recommended way is search "User Header Search Paths" in your Xcode help menu.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6.1.1 also requires you to set Search Paths->Always Search User Paths to 'Yes' ... and have User Header Search Paths as specified in above posts.