# Error Building Cocos2dx in XCode after adding Crypto++ library

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

After adding cryptopp to my project that's using cocos2dx, I was prompted with this error:

[image]

ioapi.h is one of cocos2dx' classes. I'm not really sure what's causing this problem. I've searched and searched for a solution and I really couldn't find one. I'm so desperate. I tried building a new cryptopp library and the error still exists. :( Can someone please help me. Thank you so much.

EDIT:
Attaching some screenshots of my Build Settings
[image: Header Search Path]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[image: Library Search Path]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[image]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: This does not appear to be related to Crypto++. It looks like ***`ioapi.h`*** is missing an include it needs. Maybe you accidentally changed a project setting when adding the Crypto++ library. Also see [User Header Search Paths for Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18414917) on Stack Overflow and [Xcode Build Setting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) on Apple Developer.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. It's not related to cryptopp but after adding it, I was prompted with this error when I tried to build. 

I will attach screenshots of my settings.